# Try YouTube API request and response

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to use YouTube Data API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), but, now, it doesn't run. I used it a few weeks ago, and all was good.
This is the error that I get [image: Google Auth Error].
When I click on the *list (by channel ID)*, this is the response:
[image: YouTube API response]

I want to use YouTube API for my web app. What can I do?
How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Comment: Have you tried to follow the instructions given by the error message you've posted above?

Comment: @stvar, yes, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Your screenshot shows you're calling the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint, not `Playlists.list` as you mentioned. Please be explicit: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello!
Seems like youtube API testing works now.
All fine!
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In any case, based on my experience this API, I wouldn't recommend to rely much of the *Try this API* functionality of the API's docs website. If only need to play (test, or debug) the raw REST API calls then use either `wget`, `curl` or [Google's Developers OAuth 2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Comment: @stvar, I didn't know about this site. Thank you very much!
Have a nice day!